# Correlation over 3 dimensions

Tags: arrays, r, correlation

I have a 3 dimensional dataset where the dimensions are var, year and date.

In my example data, there are:

- 5 dates, date1:date5
- 5 years, y1:y5
- and 5 vars, TA_JDRng, TH_JDMax, TH_JDMaxMn, TH_JDMaxSD, TH_JDMaxVar

Essentially, each variable is recorded every year on 5 specific dates.

```
data <- 
read.table(header = TRUE, 
           text = "date var y1  y2  y3  y4  y5
date1   TA_JDRng    123 80  80  80  80
date1   TH_JDMax    343 343 343 343 343
date1   TH_JDMaxMn  107.4286    107.4286    107.4286    114.1429    131.1429
date1   TH_JDMaxSD  161.2729    161.2729    161.2729    157.6234    93.4477
date1   TH_JDMaxVar 26008.9524  26008.9524  26008.9524  24845.1429  8732.4762
date2   TA_JDRng    123 80  80  80  80
date2   TH_JDMax    343 343 343 343 343
date2   TH_JDMaxMn  107.4286    107.4286    107.4286    114.1429    134.2857
date2   TH_JDMaxSD  161.2729    161.2729    161.2729    157.6234    92.0502
date2   TH_JDMaxVar 26008.9524  26008.9524  26008.9524  24845.1429  8473.2381
date3   TA_JDRng    123 80  80  80  80
date3   TH_JDMax    343 343 343 343 343
date3   TH_JDMaxMn  107.4286    107.4286    107.4286    114.1429    114.1429
date3   TH_JDMaxSD  161.2729    161.2729    161.2729    157.6234    157.6234
date3   TH_JDMaxVar 26008.9524  26008.9524  26008.9524  24845.1429  24845.1429
date4   TA_JDRng    77  99  56  56  56
date4   TH_JDMax    319 319 319 319 319
date4   TH_JDMaxMn  180.7143    180.7143    180.7143    180.7143    180.7143
date4   TH_JDMaxSD  162.8903    162.8903    162.8903    162.8903    162.8903
date4   TH_JDMaxVar 26533.2381  26533.2381  26533.2381  26533.2381  26533.2381
date5   TA_JDRng    177 77  99  56  56
date5   TH_JDMax    65  319 319 319 319
date5   TH_JDMaxMn  59.2857 180.7143    180.7143    180.7143    180.7143
date5   TH_JDMaxSD  13.901  162.8903    162.8903    162.8903    162.8903
date5   TH_JDMaxVar 193.2381    26533.2381  26533.2381  26533.2381  26533.2381")
```

Things become slightly unstuck at this point. I know I need to convert this into an array and I have found the appropriate method to do this by.

`dataArray <- simplify2array(by(data, data$XorYorZ, as.matrix))`

What I am unclear of, to begin with, is whether I should be splitting (`data$XorYorZ`) by date or year, or whether it does not matter.

```
dataArray <- simplify2array(by(data, data$date, as.matrix))
dim(dataArray)
```

I'm not 100% convinced this looks correct as we still retain the columns for date and var. I'm aware they would not just disappear as if by magic, I just do not know if a) this needs to be addressed, and if so, then b) how to do this.

Again, I'm aware of how to calculate the correlation matrix, but this, at this time does not work.

`corM <- apply(dataArray, 1:2, cor.test, unique(data$date))`
`Error in cor.test.default(newX[, i], ...) : 'x' must be a numeric vector`

I believe I understand the reason for the error, that being that text remains in the array, but I do not know how to address this. I did think about converting date and var into numeric classes, but I'm not sure this is the right approach.

Could anyone clarify on where the steps I am taking are wrong? I'm sure it's something simple but I just can't see it. Thanks for your help in advance!

If it's relevant - I am ultimately trying to establish what correlation there is between years and vars. I am attempting to establish if there is high correlation, and if so, then I can drop some years.

Comment: Try `simplify2array(by(data[, 3:7], list(data$date, data$var), as.matrix))`. You don't need to split the whole dataset, as the whole dataset contains the names of the dates and the variables. My understanding is that you only need the numeric data, so select it as the first argument of the `by` command.

Comment: Thanks @coffeinjunky, that resolves part of the problem! Can you explain why it is splitting by both date and var? I thought I only had to split by one. Thanks

Comment: I wrote `list(date, var)` just for illustration, no particular other reason. Sorry if that was confusing. The main point is that you need to avoid making a matrix out of a dataframe that contains characters, since then all variables are converted to character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help, and specifically thank you @flyingfille for explicitly pointing out that the data is not pairwise. I continued looking whilst my question was up and there are options available to calculate the correlation over these dimensions. However, this is, it turns out, not necessary in this case.

As stated at the close of my question, I was trying to focus on the relationship between years and vars, the difficulty being that each year/var had multiple sample dates.

I have taken the approach of looking at each variable seperately and calculating the covariance matrix for each. The method is as follows:

```
pacman::p_load(dplyr)

#First I split the data and take note of the names of the variables
dataSplit <- data %>% gather(year, value, -date, -var) %>% split(., .$var)
varNames <- names(dataSplit)

lapply(1:length(dataSplit), function(x) { 
#Data is converted to a [year,date] matrix
  dataMat <- dataSplit[[x]] %>% spread(year, value) %>% select(-var, -date) %>% as.matrix

#Correlation matrix for the matrix is calculated      
  dataCor <- round(cor(dataMat), digits = 2)

#The correlation matrix is flattened (using the function below) to simplify analysis of the results across the many variables.
  flattenCorrMatrix(dataCor) %>% unclass %>% as_data_frame %>% mutate(var = varNames[x]) %>% select(var, everything())
}) %>% bind_rows


flattenCorrMatrix <- function(cormat) {
  ut <- upper.tri(cormat)
  data.frame(
    row = rownames(cormat)[row(cormat)[ut]],
    column = rownames(cormat)[col(cormat)[ut]],
    cor  =(cormat)[ut]
  )
}
```

Although not outputting correlation in the traditional correlation matrix format, this has achieved the desired result, clarifying which years have considerable correlation and may be removed.

```
# A tibble: 50 x 4
        var    row column   cor
      <chr> <fctr> <fctr> <dbl>
 1 TA_JDRng     y1     y2 -0.84
 2 TA_JDRng     y1     y3  0.99
 3 TA_JDRng     y2     y3 -0.91
 4 TA_JDRng     y1     y4 -0.06
 5 TA_JDRng     y2     y4 -0.49
 6 TA_JDRng     y3     y4  0.09
 7 TA_JDRng     y1     y5 -0.06
 8 TA_JDRng     y2     y5 -0.49
 9 TA_JDRng     y3     y5  0.09
10 TA_JDRng     y4     y5  1.00
# ... with 40 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `cor.test` for paired samples. Edit: You cannot use all the numerical data in your matrix. Only you could do for example the correlation between year1 and year2 by `cor.mat(data$y1, data$y2)`. But I guess it is not what you want.

Your data structure is different, you have a continuous dependent variable and 3 (in)dependent variables. Then you will have to apply a multiple linear regression and factorize your variables. Have a look [here](http://www.statmethods.net/stats/regression.html).

In addition, it may be the case that your variables "date" and "year" are correlated. In this case, I would consider transform them into 1 time variable and perform a [specific regression for time-series data](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/4/8).

Comment: Thanks @flyingfille. Thanks for pointing out the paired issue, it made my internet searches simpler. I have still seen methods where correlation across multiple dimensions is possible but in this case it doesn't seem practical or desirable.

Multi-model inference is the stage that will follow this, so unfortunately regression is not the solution! I simply needed to reduce the number of years of data required (if correlated) to simplify the modelling process going forwards. 

However, I've established a solution to this problem now. I thank you for your help